# How do I have to mock patch in this use case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

The initial scenerio is writing tests for functions from a library (lib.py).

lib.py:

```
def fun_x(val):
  # does something with val
  return result

def fun(val):
  x = fun_x(val)
  # does seomthing with x
  return result
```

test__lib.py

```
import pytest
import lib

def lib_fun_x_mocked(val):
  return "qrs"

def test_fun():
  assert lib.fun("abc") == "xyz"
```

But `lib.fun_x()` does something very expensive or requires a resource not reliably available or not determinisitc. So I want to subsitute it with a mock function such that when the test `test_fun()` is executed `lib.fun()` uses `lib_fun_x_mocked()` instead of `fun_x()` from its local scope.

So far I'm running into cryptic error messages when I try to apply mock/patch recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in fixture [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) provided by pytest.

```
import lib

def lib_fun_x_mocked(some_val):  # still takes an argument
    return "qrs"

def test_fun(monkeypatch):
    with monkeypatch.context() as mc:
        mc.setattr(lib, 'fun_x', lib_fun_x_mocked)
        result = lib.fun('abc')
    assert result == 'qrs'
```

Also as a side note, if you are testing the function `fun` you shouldn't be asserting the output of `fun_x` within that test. You should be asserting that `fun` behaves in the way that *you* expect given a certain value is returned by `fun_x`.

Comment: how is this convoluted? this looks straightforward to me. also this is using the _pytest_ framework. if you go to the docs for monkeypatch that I provided you will see that this is part of the _pytest_ framework. all fixtures are automatically imported into test files hence why we don’t need to import _pytest_ itself for this test.